# Issue dealing with white space with Ruby regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a simple script expression that allows me to identify the java files in a directory that have a private constructor.  I have had some luck but I want my script to acknowledge there is white space between the access modifier and the constructor name but not care if it is a space or n spaces or a tab or n tabs etc.

I am trying to use...

```
"private\s+"+object_name
```

but the + (1 or more) is not finding a constructor with 2 spaces between the modifier and the constructor name.

I know I am missing something.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is the full code if it helps...

```
!#/usr/bin/ruby

path = ARGV[0]
if path.nil?
    puts "missing path argument"
    exit
end

entries = Dir.entries( path )

entries.each do |file_name|
    file_name = file_name.rstrip
    if ( file_name.end_with? "java" )
        text = File.read( path+file_name )
        object_name = file_name.chomp( ".java" )
        search_str = "private\s+"+object_name
            matches = text.match( Regexp.escape( search_str ) )
            if ( !matches.nil? && matches.length > 0 )
                puts matches
            end
        end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double-quoted string reads `"\s"` as `" "`, no problems with that, but prefer use single-quoted in this case. `Regexp.escape` removes the funcionality of the regex's symbols of the string. `private +` (`"\s"` is `" "`) is converted to `private\ \+` and, with `match`, will try to find the string `private +object_name`, what is not what you want. Remove the `Regexp.escape` and it should work well.

Comment: I didn't realize the difference between single and double quotes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to escape the \ in your Ruby string and also Regexp.escape your object name and not the whole regex including the whitespace matcher, e.g.,

```
[...]
search_regex = Regexp.new("private\\s+" + Regexp.escape(object_name))
matches = text.match(search_regex)
```

As @LBg also points out, if you want to use + concatenation, better to use single quotes that won't require escaping the \. Or use doubles with substitution as in:

```
search_regex = Regexp.new("private\\s+#{Regexp.escape(object_name)}")
```